# delayed_job version for active records?

Tags: database, activerecord, rake, delayed-job, migrate

I can't do `rake db:migrate`, it throws an error

Run `rake gems:install` to install delayed_job

I think the delayed_job version is the problem.

These are the Gemfile.lock relevant lines

```
delayed_job (2.1.4)
  activesupport (~> 3.0)
  daemons
delayed_job_data_mapper (1.0.0.rc)
  delayed_job (~> 2.1)
  dm-aggregates
  dm-core
  dm-observer
```

Comment: It throws error **What?** error can you specify that

Comment: " Run rake gems:install to install delayed_job "

Comment: why dont you run **bundle install** or **bundle** and see if the error replicates